# What is wrong with my MiTeX 2.9 update?

Tags: miktex2.9

I updated my MikTeX 2.9 two days ago.
After that I cannot run it.
The screen has only one line appears and ask to install 
a package  tex\generic\dehyph-exptl\dehypht-x-2017-03-31.tex
everytimes.
So How should I fix it?

[image]

Comment: To install *what*?

Comment: a package \dehypht-x-2017-03-31.tex

Comment: It is not a package, it's a file in the `dehyph-exptl` package. Did you install this package?

Comment: The package will be installed from ?! you may need to choose the server.

Comment: It is automatically choose, it never had problem before.

Comment: Remove the check mark from the line in the dialog box that says `Always show this dialog before installing packages` and click `Install`. No popup should occur for subsequent package installations then

Comment: I need the dialog box to know what is going on. Removing it will not help the package to be successfully installed.

Comment: @Bernard I did not install it myself....it used to be o.k.

Comment: The problem is solved. The downloaded file use date as file name. It is looking for 2017-03-17 but the downloaded file is 2018-03-17 etc.

Comment: the 2017 version of dehyph has been removed. If your system is still looking for it you should probably update the language settings. And also update the package database.